# How to use the output of the ar() function in my code

Tags: r, autoregressive-models

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ9gY.jpg

I am using the `ar()` function, to get an Estimation of the AR-coefficients. Now, I'd like to estimate the next value of the series, using these estimations, but don't know how to get them, without typing them out by myself. If I try to get the output by typing `ar(...)[2]`, I get the results, but this is an object of the form "List of one"; so I can't use them for further calculations.

Comment: `predict()` . Have a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181533/prediction-of-time-series-using-ar1-on-the-difference-of-the-time-series-in-r) question

Comment: Please consider posting the code as text and not as an image

Comment: Also, doesn't `ar(...)[[2]]` solve the problem?

Comment: @teunbrand well, it gives me the values that I want, but my problem is, that the only way I see to do calculations with this, is to type the numbers out by myself and the into my code again. It says, that ar(...)[2] is a List of 1 object, but I don't know how to  access these values. I tried ar(...)[2,1], ar(...)[2,2] etc. but that's the wrong dimension for this object.

Comment: Sorry my bad, should have been `ar(...)[[1]]`

Comment: @teunbrand no, that only gives the result 4, for the number of coefficients